# Boot problem: error while loading shared libraries libpam.so.0 cannot open shared object file

Tags: boot, 18.04

When I try to boot Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I get `error while loading shared libraries libpam.so.0 cannot open shared object file` error so cannot boot to the login screen. How can I fix this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You mean libpam.so.0 (like in your screen shot)?

Comment: yes the screen shot.

Comment: didn't notice the misspelling not libssl but libpam, thanks for the editting

Comment: I am not going to boot this machine successfully anymore. maybe broken. so I tried to get the home user files by mounting the disk on windows anyway, but even windows doesn't recognize the partition, so I cannot mount the partition as drive and cannot get the user data. please don't say I lost even the user data also... would anyone help me? or I'll create a new question here.

Comment: You might try booting an install media in the "Try" mode to mount and read your files.  Windows may not be able to read the ext4 filesystem. A new question on file recovery would be good.